# Why doesn't nested parameter expansion work correctly in GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

Using a `bash` runner, is there any reason why the following variable expansion shouldn't work?

```
variables:
  GIT_BRANCH: "${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME:-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:-$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH}}"

job1:
  script:
    - echo $GIT_BRANCH
```

The job outputs `}`.

I'm using GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.1.8-ee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These expansions are done by GitLab CI, not by bash, so they probably simply can't handle nested expansions as robustly as bash can.

They probably think the variable name is everything up to the next `}`, so `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME:-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:-$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` without a closing curly brace. That would explain why there is a leftover `}` when the dust settles.

Answer (score 2):

Gitlab variables can not perform bash operations as you try here.

Gitlab understands `${VARIABLE_NAME}`

In your case

```
${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME:-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:-$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH}}
```

Gitlab tries to find the variable `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME:-${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:-$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH}`

But this variable doesn't exist, so it only outputs `}`

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the other answers, this syntax won't expand how you expect. As a workaround, you might be able to use `rules:variables:` to get the same effect.

```yaml
my_job:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME'
      variables:
        GIT_BRANCH: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      variables:
        GIT_BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - when: on_success
  variables:
    GIT_BRANCH: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

You could also consider simply setting the variable directly in the job script using `export`. Then the bash variable expansion will work as expected.